# Unable to resolve host error while using accelerate mode in s3

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to amazon aws sdk for java. I have v2.6 of aws sdk for java. My problem is when i enable accelerate mode using
*`s3Client.setS3ClientOptions(S3ClientOptions.builder().setAccelerateModeEnabled(true).build());`* 
I get exception "Unable to resolve host "s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname" on uploading file. It worked fine in previous version of sdk. I dont know how to fix this issue. can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Creating AmazonS3Client using the below code solved my problem,

```
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
    configuration.setMaxErrorRetry(3);
    configuration.setConnectionTimeout(501000);
    configuration.setSocketTimeout(501000);
    configuration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

    sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider(), configuration);

    if (sS3Client == null) {
        sS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        sS3Client.setS3ClientOptions(S3ClientOptions.builder().setAccelerateModeEnabled(true).build());

        // wrap the call in a thread since we make a network call.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sS3Client.setBucketAccelerateConfiguration(AppConstants.BUCKET_NAME,
                        new BucketAccelerateConfiguration(BucketAccelerateStatus.Enabled));
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        }).start();

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You can refer to this link https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/473

Comment: It doesn't help. S3 throws other error: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied...). Do you hav any idea?

Comment: Please make sure that the bucket is already created. You can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533707/android-aws-s3-access-denied